# ES6 (Webpack) single file for each module - How to make variables globally available without using window.VARIABLE

Tags: module, ecmascript-6

I'm using React and one thing I didn't figure out yet is how to share variables with multiple components/modules. Right now I use window.VARIABLE = ... As this makes developers cringe, I wonder if there's a better way to do this without writing allot of boilerplate code and without bringing in Redux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Webpack is just a tool that will bundle multiple files into a single one.
His job is not to connect react components.

Using global variables can be a way to share data between 2 components React but the best thing you can do is to give the variable as component properties (if you don't have to manipulate it).
If you need to share a state (a variable that can be manipulated), you need to use a tool like redux.